# javascript regular expression , what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var regExpress = "/^([a-zA-Z0-9\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\+\=\|\}\{'\"\;\:\?\/\.\,\s]*)/i";

if (strMessage.search(regExpress) == -1) { alert("error occurs"); }
```

I want to allow almost all characters.
I want to use it because of some formatting issue from some other application. 
So whenever user cuts and pastes from another application, 
it causes to add some weird character which I need to take care of it. 
But every time I am getting -1 return which is not correct.

What is wrong in this regular expression?

Comment: You are *massively* over-escaping. It is nonsense to escape every character. `/^([a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()\-+=|}{'";:?/.,\s]*)/i` is your regex.

Comment: Somehow I am missing a dollar sign at the end, and I think that `search()` should be a `match()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't double quote the expression, remove the quotes, ie:

```
var regex = /.../i;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myNewString = strMessage.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/i, "");
```

Replace the characters inside the brackets after the `^` with whatever you want to allow.

Comment: That's not the same as "error occurs", and does not really answer the question.

Comment: What is the question then?  The regex posted is invalid.  They don't belong in quotation marks in JavaScript.  This is how you would remove characters using a regex.

Comment: Although that is true, your regexp and the replacement are not consistent with the question...